# C++ Quick Sort Implementation, not having the right output

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, iterator, quicksort

I am implementing the quick sort algorithm from Cormen's Algorithm book(CLRS).

```
 vector<int> numbers = {5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 13, -6, 0, 3, 1, -2};

 My_Quick_Sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
```

it has no error, but it can not sort the numbers.

The pseudo code in the book is like the following.

1. Quicksort(A, p, r)
2. if p < r
3. q = Partition(A, p, r)
4. Quicksort(A, p, q-1)
5. Quicksort(A, q+1, r)
6. Partition(A, p, r)
7. x = A[r]
8. i = p - 1
9. for j = p to r - 1
10. _*_*_i= i+1;
11. _*_*_exchange A[i] with A[j]
12. exchange A[i+1] with A[r]
13. return i + 1;

My implementation is like the following.

```
 template<typename T>
 void Swap(T a, T b)
 {
     typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
     value_type temp;
     temp = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = temp;
 }

 template<typename T>
 int Partition(T begin, T end)
 {
     typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
     value_type x;
         x = *end;
     T i = begin - 1;
     T j;
     for(j = begin; j != end+1; ++j)
     {
         if ( x >= *j )
         {
              i++;
              Swap(i, j);
         }
         Swap(i+1, end);
     }
     return static_cast<int>(distance(begin, i) + 1);
 }

 template<typename T>
 void Q_Sort(T begin, T end)
 {
     auto length = end - begin;
     if (length < 2) return;

     if ( begin != end )
     {
         auto pivot = Partition(begin, end);
         Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot - 1);
         Q_Sort(begin + pivot + 1, end);
     }
 }
```

Anybody has any idea about my code? It works, but does not do the sorting.
For example, if I input 
shuffle: 13, 0, -6, 6, -2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 7,

output is like the following
My_Quick_Sort: -6, -2, 0, 6, 13, 0, 5, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 7,

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.

Comment: Why not use `std::qsort()` ?

Comment: I want to practice implementing recursion and iterator, that's why I do not use qsort. The problem is I do not get any error message, so it's hard to spot what I am missing.

Comment: `Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot - 1);` and `Q_Sort(begin + pivot + 1, end);` - when does `begin + pivot` get sorted?

Comment: *it has no error, but it can not sort the numbers* LOL

Comment: begin + pivot is where I put pivot. After pivot, I have bigger elements and before pivot, I have smaller elements. That is what CLRS does with quick sort.

Comment: Can you show `MyQuickSort` functions also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about your implementation:

Firstly, To simplify your Q_Sort method and the logic, I would return an iterator from the partition method rather than an int. This will simplify the Q_Sort as below:

```
template<typename T>
void Q_Sort(T begin, T end)
{
    if ( begin < end )
    {
        T pivot = Partition(begin, end);
        Q_Sort(begin, pivot - 1);
        Q_Sort( pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Please note that you do not need the check  "if (length < 2) return;"

Secondly, in the partition method in for loop your terminating condition "j != end+1" does not match the pseudocode. It should be end - 1. Here is the new code for the Partition method. Please note that I am assuming the second parameter (end) points to the actual last value rather than pointing to the value beyond last.

```
template<typename T>
T Partition(T begin, T end)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type value_type;
    value_type x;

    x = *end;
    T i = begin - 1;

    for(T j = begin; j < end; ++j)
    {
        if ( x >= *j )
        {
            i++;
            Swap(i, j);
        }
    }

    Swap(i+1, end);
    //return static_cast<int>(distance(begin, i) + 1);
    return i+1;
}
```

Lastly, I believe the pseudocode assumes the second parameter to be the last element but the iterator numbers.end() points to the position beyond last element. So you will need to change the call to quick sort as below:

```
vector<int>::iterator iterEnd = numbers.end();
--iterEnd;
Q_Sort(numbers.begin(), iterEnd);
```

After considering the above points you should be able to sort correctly.

Comment: Good suggestions, but note that s/he's calling it as `My_Quick_Sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());`, and that calls `Partition(begin, end);`, so the last parameter `Partition()` must indicate one-past-the-end of the range (as usual) rather than an iterator to the actual last element. This implies another bug: the first recursive call to `Q_Sort()` should be `Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot);`.

Comment: When we call My_Quick_sort with numbers.end() like you said `My_Quick_Sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());` then the first call to Partition(begin,end) would result in a logic error inside the Partition method at the line `x = *end;`. At this point end points to one past the last element and x would have a bad value.

Comment: Probably yes. I might have misread your reply the first time. Since you agree with my reply then that implies I agree with you :)

Comment: Yes this works, but I had to make some more tricky modifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In almost ever quicksort() algorithm that fails, the overwhelming culprit is the partition algorithm that is failing to properly exclude the pivot slot or incorrect math on the low and high side therein. This is no different. [See an example live](http://ideone.com/yE4J7f) that does in-place partitioning.

In your case, I would ensure that your parition algorithm assumes the region being partitioned starts at `begin` and ends at the element *prior* to `end` In other words this:

```
for(j = begin; j != end+1; ++j)
```

should be this:

```
for(j = begin; j != end; ++j)
```

The second overwhelming cause for failed quicksort() is failing to skip *just the pivot* from the previous partitioning run. if you do the right thing mentioned in the code before, then this:

```
 auto pivot = Partition(begin, end);
 Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot - 1);  // <<=== -1 should not be here.
 Q_Sort(begin + pivot + 1, end);
```

Should actually be this:

```
 auto pivot = Partition(begin, end);
 Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot);
 Q_Sort(begin + pivot + 1, end);
```

Remember, C++ iterators run to `end()`, which is the first element *after* the last one you want anyway, so no -1 is needed. Given a sequence such as.

```
int ar[] = { 5,6,2,7,9,8 }
```

and suppose the pivot slot was at the fourth slot (pivot=3), then

```
 Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot);    // includes 5,6,2, NOT 7
 Q_Sort(begin + pivot + 1, end);  // includes 9,8, again, NOT 7
```

I know it may seem odd, but if you accidentally did NOT want to skip the pivot slot, then the calls would look like this:

```
 Q_Sort(begin, begin + pivot);   // beginning through (pivot-1)
 Q_Sort(begin + pivot, end);     // pivot through end
```

which is another common mistake in quicksort() implementations.

Work on these fundamentals and you should be good.

Comment: Good catches, but note that if as you suggest `Partition()` interprets its 2nd argument as the position of the final element (rather than one-past-the-end as is usually the case with C++ iterators), then the initial call to `Partition()` is buggy and should be changed to `auto pivot = Partition(begin, end - 1);`.